# In zsh, difference between cat <(cat) vs cat | cat vs cat =(cat)?

Tags: zsh, subshell, process-substitution

I expected `cat <(cat)` and `cat | cat` to do the same thing: copy lines from stdin to stdout. My understanding was that both would execute a `cat` in a subshell, redirect the subshell `cat`'s stdout to a temporary named pipe, and then execute another `cat` in the current shell with its stdin redirected to the pipe.

Instead, `cat <(cat)` lets me type at my terminal, but none of the input lines get copied and `^D` fails to signal `EOF`; `cat | cat` works as expected though.

As a further experiment, I checked if `cat =(cat)` has similar difficulties as `cat <(cat)`, but it works as I expected: all of stdin up to a `^D` gets copied to stdout in one go.

Can anyone help me understand what zsh is doing under the hood?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. `a | b` connects `STDOUT` from `a` and `STDIN` from `b` just by using [`dup/dup2`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dup&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en). Both commands are executed in parallel.
2. `a =(b)` replaces the argument to `a` with an temporary filename. `b` will be executed before `a` as the temporary file needs to be created before it can be passed to `a`
3. `a <(b)` replaces the argument to `a` with an named pipe. `a` and `b` run in parallel. This is now where it gets a little bit complicated:

   • `b` is in the background and can't read from the terminal. You can test it yourself by using `strace -p $PID` to attach to your second cat process to see the process.

   • `a` in the meantime tries to read from the named pipe but can't read anything as as `b` can't read.

   • This means you basically have a deadlock where `a` tries to read from `b` but `b` can't read from `STDIN` and can't write to `a`

More information about background process and terminal from [man bash](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

> To facilitate the implementation of the user interface to job
>   control, the operating system maintains the notion of a **current
>   terminal process group ID**. Members of this process group 
>   (processes  whose  process group ID is equal to the current terminal
>   process group ID) receive keyboard-generated signals such as
>   **SIGINT**. These processes are said to be in the **foreground**. **Background** processes are those whose process group ID differs from the
>   terminal's; such processes are immune to  keyboard-generated  signals.
>   Only  foreground    processes  are  allowed to read from or, if the
>   user so specifies with stty tostop, write to the terminal. 
>   Background processes which attempt to read from  (write  to  when 
>   stty tostop is  in  effect) the terminal are sent a **SIGTTIN
>   (SIGTTOU)** signal by the kernel's terminal driver, which, unless
>   caught, suspends the process.

Comment: Great, thank you--this cleared up a lot!

Comment: Note when not interactive, zsh redirects the standard input of _background_ commands (including those in `<(cmd)`) to `/dev/null`, so the behavior differs (`zsh -c 'cat <(cat)'` returns immediately and doesn't output anything).